# lsof -i and nmap output different

Tags: linux, nmap, ports

To test my PostgreSQL, I had to find its port number.
I ran two different commands to see what it is:

- `nmap localhost`
- `lsof -i | grep postgres`

[image: nmap and lsof outputs]

I was confused when the two commands returned different port numbers, but surprised when I found out that nmap returned the accurate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was caused by two reasons, both relating to how I executed `lsof`.

- `sudo lsof` tends to return more information than simply `lsof`
- `lsof` tends to convert port numbers to port names. In this case, it converted `localhost:5432` to `localhost:postgresql`.

I was able to see the proper output once I ran `sudo lsof -i -P | grep postgres`